# Emacs not displaying properly after Ubuntu update

Tags: 18.04, apt, server, updates, emacs

I just spun up a droplet (DigitalOcean) running Ubuntu 18.04. Emacs works fine. After running apt upgrade, emacs is behaving strangely. My cursor is always off by one line and some elements don't render properly. I've tried rebuilding the droplet a few times with the same effect.

Has anyone else run into this?

Packages upgraded:

```
Get:1 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 base-files amd64 10.1ubuntu2.8 [59.9 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 bsdutils amd64 1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [60.3 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-bin amd64 0.130ubuntu3.9 [10.2 kB]
Get:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-core all 0.130ubuntu3.9 [48.2 kB]
Get:5 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools all 0.130ubuntu3.9 [9568 B]
Get:6 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libext2fs2 amd64 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3 [157 kB]
Get:7 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 e2fsprogs amd64 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3 [391 kB]
Get:8 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 [56.1 kB]
Get:9 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 [1102 kB]
Get:10 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnss-systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 [104 kB]
Get:11 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 [107 kB]
Get:12 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 [2912 kB]
Get:13 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 [206 kB]
Get:14 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 [13.9 kB]
Get:15 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [20.1 kB]
Get:16 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libblkid1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [124 kB]
Get:17 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [136 kB]
Get:18 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libfdisk1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [164 kB]
Get:19 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsmartcols1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [83.7 kB]
Get:20 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 fdisk amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [108 kB]
Get:21 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 util-linux amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [903 kB]
Get:22 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mount amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [107 kB]
Get:23 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cpio amd64 2.12+dfsg-6ubuntu0.18.04.1 [86.2 kB]
Get:24 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-base all 4.5ubuntu1.1 [17.7 kB]
Get:25 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04 [1414 kB]
Get:26 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5 [1300 kB]
Get:27 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04 [203 kB]
Get:28 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6-stdlib amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04 [1709 kB]
Get:29 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04 [1610 kB]
Get:30 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04 [533 kB]
Get:31 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.3 [498 kB]
Get:32 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 uuid-runtime amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6 [34.8 kB]
Get:33 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcom-err2 amd64 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3 [8848 B]
Get:34 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgcrypt20 amd64 1.8.1-4ubuntu1.2 [417 kB]
Get:35 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libss2 amd64 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3 [11.1 kB]
Get:36 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libidn2-0 amd64 2.0.4-1.1ubuntu0.2 [48.7 kB]
Get:37 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgnutls30 amd64 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.3 [646 kB]
Get:38 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libdevmapper1.02.1 amd64 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2 [127 kB]
Get:39 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 dmsetup amd64 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2 [74.5 kB]
Get:40 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 file amd64 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3 [22.1 kB]
Get:41 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmagic1 amd64 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3 [68.7 kB]
Get:42 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmagic-mgc amd64 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3 [184 kB]
Get:43 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libbsd0 amd64 0.8.7-1ubuntu0.1 [41.6 kB]
Get:44 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libisc-export169 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [163 kB]
Get:45 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libdns-export1100 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [749 kB]
Get:46 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 [1171 kB]
Get:47 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-data all 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 [4540 B]
Get:48 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libicu60 amd64 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 [8054 kB]
Get:49 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxml2 amd64 2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3 [663 kB]
Get:50 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5 [613 kB]
Get:51 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 sudo amd64 1.8.21p2-3ubuntu1.2 [427 kB]
Get:52 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3 [49.4 kB]
Get:53 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3 [1153 kB]
Get:54 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3 [476 kB]
Get:55 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3 [5436 kB]
Get:56 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3 [70.6 kB]
Get:57 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-minimal amd64 1.417.4 [2704 B]
Get:58 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libirs160 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [19.1 kB]
Get:59 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 dnsutils amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [145 kB]
Get:60 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 bind9-host amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [53.6 kB]
Get:61 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libbind9-160 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [27.6 kB]
Get:62 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libisccfg160 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [48.5 kB]
Get:63 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libisccc160 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [17.9 kB]
Get:64 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libdns1100 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [966 kB]
Get:65 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libisc169 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [237 kB]
Get:66 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 liblwres160 amd64 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11 [34.5 kB]
```

Comment: Works fine in `tmux`. I guess that's my workaround for now...